# Adding a css-class to a div when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, less

I would like to add a css-class (.shrink) to a menu-bar (#secondary-menu) in a Bootstrap 3 website with LESS, when the menu reaches a top-margin position of 75px while scrolling down. The menu-bar stays fixed at 75px using [sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/). However, I would like to change it's appearance with the shrink-class.

Unfortunately, I don't get my jQuery code working in the current form. The shrink-class is constantly applied. On its own, the CSS-classes work.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- service-nav -->
    <div id="service-nav" class="shrink">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-comment fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-search fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></li>
          </ul>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.service-nav -->
```

**LESS:**

```
#service-nav {
    background: #000;

    width: 100%;

    li  {
        padding: 40px 60px 25px 60px;
        color: #808080;
    }

    i {
        display: block;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }   

    @shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    .box-shadow(@shadow);
}

.shrink {

    li {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    i {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    p {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    $("#service-nav").removeClass("shrink");
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 75) {
        $("#service-nav").addClass("shrink");
      }
    }
```

Comment: The CSS you have pasted isn't valid.

Comment: I'd say it's less or scss.

Comment: @Morpheus Sorry, I forgot to note that I use LESS and when compiled it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing bracket `);`. Should be:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
   $("#service-nav").removeClass("shrink");
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll <= 75) {
      $("#service-nav").addClass("shrink");
   }
});
```

Comment: That seems to work. However, how can I determine that the div reached a top-margin position of 75px? At the moment it is adding the css-class after scrolling 75px down.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but try `var scroll = $(".somediv").offset().top;`

Comment: Adapted with the following code (which considers the div-height over #secondary-nav) it is working: `if (scroll >= 650) {
      $("#service-nav").addClass("shrink");
      }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var a = $('#service-nav');
    var p = a.offset().top;
    var q = $(window).scrollTop();
    var r = $('#service-nav').parent().offset().top;
    if (p - q < 75) {
        a.addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        if (p - r < 75) {
            a.removeClass("shrink");
        }
    }
});
```